# Replacing javascript random number generator with my own JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to show my data in a D3 graph. I've followed the tutorial and end up at this bit of code:

```
  // 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number
  var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) {
    return {
      "y": d3.randomUniform(1)()
    }
  })
```

Instead of randomly generating numbers, I want to feed in my own JSON data. This is what I tried:

```
var obj = {
    y: "1",
    y: "6",
    y: "10"
};

var dataset = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

However, when I do this it doesn't work. For comparison this is what the old code spat out (from console.log):

```
0: {y: 0.8863000631639524}
1: {y: 0.730344915698621}
2: {y: 0.23216952106703048}
3: {y: 0.6065558075691728}
```

This is what my new code spits out:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
(index):119 {"y":"10"}
d3.v5.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNC0,NaN,0,NaN,…".
```

The complete code is here around line 41:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mt1rngqo/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataset is an array of objects that each have a field `y` that is a number, not a string

```js
var dataset = [
    {y: 1},
    {y: 6},
    {y: 10}
];


//var dataset = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(dataset);
```